# While cleaning and bulding in netbeans -Xlint:unchecked error getting and jar file not running

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

While I try to clean and build .jar in Netbeans, a red line appear in console:
 Note: G:\CSE-310-Lab\GUI practice\IMPuzzle\src\Game.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

But .jar created successfully and while try to open jar, it doesn't open.
What is the problem? How to fix?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to run jar?

Comment: When trying to run created .jar file, it doesn't run and no error occurs.. But when I run the file in Netbeans ,it does work properly.

Comment: did you try to recompile it with -Xlint:unchecked ?

Comment: Sorry! I don't know about -Xlint:unchecked and how to recompile with it.

Comment: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1301554

Comment: sounds like the main class attribute is not in the manifest file, or you have dependencies that are not packaged into the jar, or not located where hte jar expects them. try to run the jar on the commadn line, not by double-clicking on it, as then you should be  able to see possible errors.

Comment: Thanks @Stultuske !  I got relief from -Xlint:unchecked error, fixed those but still .jar not opening,,

Comment: Thanks @hoijui, tryng

Comment: Thanks@ All, I'm done successfully!

Comment: ahh good to hear @Touhidul_MTI :-), maybe upvote useful comments and/or answer your own question, so it can be usefull to others in the future with the same problem.